# A Probability Question From HW - Why a Random Variable Has Two Distribution?

Tags: probability, random-variables, random

> Assume we have a random number generator that can generate a random
> number uniformly distributed in the range $[0, 1]$. If now we want to
> use this generator to generate a random number X that has a negative
> exponential distribution $f_X(x) = ae^{−bx} (x ≥ 0)$, where $a, b \geq 0$.
>
> Suppose the random number generator generates $0.8$. What should be the
> value for X?

I am totally confused... I dont get the point of this question. The random number generator $X \sim U[0, 1]$ according to the question. But why $X$ is negative exponential in the following sentences?

Could anyone give some hints about the model of this question? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They never say that $X$ is uniform. $X$ is negative exponential. The uniform variable is unnamed.

They want you to describe a way to transform $U[0,1]$ variable into a negative exponential variable, then apply that transformation to $0.8$. Technically, there are many ways of doing this, but I think there is one that stands out as better than most others: just apply the inverse of the cumulative distribution function (for the negative exponential $X$) on $0.8$.

Comment: Thx for your answer. What I am confused is **If now we want to use this generator to generate a random number X**. That is, the uniform number generator should be equal to $X$. Why can generate a exponential distribution?

Comment: @standerQiu You can't just take half the sentence off and expect the meaning to be retained. "If now we want to use this generator to generate a random number X **that has a negative exponential distribution**" is more correct. We have a uniform generator, and we want to use that (along with some mathematical trickery) to make negative exponential numbers, and these numbers are called $X$. The generator by itself cannot generate negative exponential numbers. We need to modify it. This modification is the core of this problem.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your answer!